# Jquery validation engine wrong position

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I have been facing this issue. I tried many things but no one worked. My validation error on this page always visible on left side. This is my vaildation engine jquery. Please help.

```
$("#register_form").validationEngine({
                     showOneMessage: true,
                     scroll : false,
                     maxErrorsPerField: 1,
                     promptPosition: "bottomLeft",
                     updatePromptsPosition: true,
                     autoPositionUpdate: true,
        });
      });
```

**HTML**
This is my form.

```
 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" id="register_form">
        <div class="col-100">

        <input type="text" class=" twidh validate[required, minSize[2]] " maxlength="60" placeholder="Your Name" name="name" id="rname" />
        <span id="runame" class="errroes"></span> </div>
    <div class="col-100">
        <input type="text" class=" twidh validate[required, custom[email]]" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="remail" id="remail" onblur="validateEmail()" />
        <span id="runame" class="errroes"></span> </div>

    <div class="col-100">
        <input type="password" class=" twidh validate[required, minSize[6]]" placeholder="Your Password" name="password" id="rpassword" />
        <span class="errroes" id="rpwd"></span> </div>
    <div class="col-100">
        <input type="text" class=" twidh validate[required, custom[onlyNumber] ,minSize[10],maxSize[10]]" maxlength="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" name="mobile" id="phone" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-100">

        <div class="text-hea" id="gender">Gender</div>
        <div class="twidh">
            <div class="names">
                <input type="radio" class="radioo" value="M" id="male" name="sex" /> Male </div>
            <div class="names">
                <input type="radio" class="radioo" value="F" id="female" name="sex" checked="checked" /> Female
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link" style="text-align:left !important"> By clicking Register, you agree to <strong>Terms of Use</strong> and <a href="http://www.shopes.in/return-policy.php"><strong>Privacy Policy.</strong></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-100">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="ss1 st" name="register" value="Register Now" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It is hard to know the problem without seeing it.

Comment: @NisargShah: I have added my form. Please check.

Comment: Guys don't downvote this question without providing the reason or answer. I have tried many option to solve this issue. Only after that I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your HTML on your [website](http://www.shopes.in/sregister). The problem is caused by a style `position: relative` on your `.link` class. You have applied it on your `OR` block, just above the form.

You can fix this quite easily by apply another `position: relative` style on your `form` element. So it would become like this:

```
<form action="/sregister.php" method="post" id="register_form" style="
    position: relative;
">
```

I just tested this on your live website, and it works pretty well. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checked issue on your site. You are using below inline styling.

```
opacity: 0.87; 
position: absolute; 
top: 241px; 
right: initial; 
margin-top: 0px; 
display: block; 
left: 489.5px;
```

but in this case "left" is not recognized as already this property is given important in strap.css.

check below code in strap.css

```
.formError {
    left: 30px !important;
}
```

Now you can update your inline styling as

```
opacity: 0.87; 
position: absolute; 
top: 241px; 
right: initial; 
margin-top: 0px; 
display: block; 
left: 489.5px !important;
```

It will work.

Comment: Those div's are generated by the Jquery validation engine. The OP can't change them easily.